# Python, update statusBar() from external class

Tags: python-3.x

I have a main.py file which contains my main code.

I have a series of classes in another preset.py file: `Job` and `Preset`, `Preset` extends/inherits from `Job`.

When I run the main.py things like `self.statusBar().showMessage("message")` are accessible.

However, when a method is running in `Presets` I would like to alter - for example - `self.statusBar().showMessage("message")`

Below are a few key code snippets, hopefully this will be enough to explain what I am trying to achieve. For note I am trying to implement QThread, so gui freezing should not be an issue.

In `main.py` the Window class is setup like this:

```
from preset import Job, Preset

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("message")
        ...

    def run(self):
        process = Presets(root_path=root_path, job_number=job_number, site_code=site_code, preset=preset)
```

In 'preset.py`:

```
class Job:
    def __init__(self, root_path, job_number, site_code):
    ...


class Presets(Job):
    def __init__(self, root_path, job_number, site_code, preset):
        super().__init__(root_path, job_number, site_code)
    ...

    def do_some_thing(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("message2")
```

In the last line `self.statusBar().showMessage("message2")` obviously will not work as it should connect to the `Window(QMainWindow)` in the main.py

Comment: Your `Window.run` method defines `process`, this should be `self.process`. That will make `Presets` methods available to `Window`

Comment: ok, so `self.process` is set in the main.py. But in the `preset.py` how do I change the `self.statusBar().showMessage("message")` in `main.py`?